# How to re-open a case in eBay although I closed the last one

Tags: ebay

I purchased an item in eBay and I found it not match the seller's description , so I opened a case for "Item I received is not as described" topic, after some chat with the seller he promised me to fix the problem in few days and ask me to close this case.

Since I am a fairly new in eBay I did a mistake and closed this case and marked in the reason that the seller should solve it in few days.

Now, I still have problems with this item and all cases I try to open say:

> You already have a case open for this item

When I select another topic the case just sent as a regular message to the seller inbox signed statement:

> Listing Status:    This message was sent while the listing was closed.

Well-known a case in eBay gives  you the option to make escalation and appeal to "ebay buyer protection".

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to open a case now?
2. Does eBay protect me after closing the last case?